# How to check Button clicked in general methode?

Tags: c#

I have tried with below

```
public partial class PaymentSearch : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   private bool button1WasClicked = false;


   protected void linkToday_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      button1WasClicked = true;
    }

  protected void ddlRecordPayment_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
  gridAllPaymentBind(1);
  }
   public void gridAllPaymentBind(int pageIndex)
   {
   if (button1WasClicked == true)
  {
   result = 3;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@result", result);
   }

 }
```

but in 'gridAllPaymentBind' methode ' button1WasClicked'  getting false value where I alredy clicked link button before dropdown list change event fire.

Comment: better put that boolean value in the session .

Comment: have you check that linkToday_Click method was call when you click?

Comment: put `private bool button1WasClicked = false;` inside a `Page.IsPostPack` check as whenever the page postbacks the value gets changed to false again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like below...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack == true)
            {
                Session["button1WasClicked "] = false;
}
}


   protected void linkToday_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Session["button1WasClicked "] = true;
    }

  protected void ddlRecordPayment_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
  gridAllPaymentBind(1);
  }
   public void gridAllPaymentBind(int pageIndex)
   {
bool button1WasClicked = (bool)Session["button1WasClicked "];
   if (button1WasClicked == true)
  {
   result = 3;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@result", result);
   }

 }
```

hope this will help you..good luck.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET by nature is stateless so the variable value will not persist between postbacks. So to make it persistent you can use either a `Session` or `ViewState`.

```
public partial class PaymentSearch : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   private bool button1WasClicked
   {
       get { return (bool)Session["button1WasClicked"]; }
       set { Session["button1WasClicked"] = value; }
   }

   protected void linkToday_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       button1WasClicked = true;
   }

  protected void ddlRecordPayment_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      gridAllPaymentBind(1);
  }

  public void gridAllPaymentBind(int pageIndex)
  {
      if (button1WasClicked == true)
      {
         result = 3;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@result", result);
      }
  }
}
```